# How to convey "Blast from the past" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

The informal expression `a blast from the past` conveys "something forcefully nostalgic."

> - someone you knew or something that existed in the past, that suddenly appears again or that you are reminded of again
>
>   *Hearing that song again was a real blast from the past.*
>     <sub>[macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/a-blast-from-the-past)</sub>
> - something or someone that surprises you because you had almost forgotten about it
> - something from the past that you remember, see, or hear again, and that reminds you of that time in your life
>
>   *That’s a blast from the past. No one has called me that for years.*
>     <sub>[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-blast-from-the-past)</sub>

Sometimes my brother goes to visit my parents and sends me a picture of an old something in my parent's house: One of my old toys, my old Advanced Dungeons & Dragons rulebooks, comics or the like. It's usually something that we haven't seen or even think about in literally years or decades, and it may have a strong emotional baggage (it's something we used to share, play together with, etc.).

When he sends me that kind of pictures via Whatsapp I'm included to just respond "a blast from the past!" and hope he'll get the meaning. A couple times I have tried

> Viaje al pasado! / Regreso al pasado!

But that doesn't really convey the full meaning.

Is there in Spanish a better translation or expression to convey what `blast from the past` means?

Comment: Without it really conveying the full meaning, I usually respond to situations like yours with "Qué recuerdos!"

Comment: Also, "¡cuántos recuerdos!"

Comment: Igual puede ser complicada de adaptar, hay una película titulada _[Blast from the Past](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_from_the_Past)_ que en España se tradujo como "Buscando a Eva" y en Hispanoamérica como "Mi novio atómico".

Comment: Part of what makes *blast from the past* such a catchy phrase is the internal rhyme.  I can't think of a translation that keeps that feature.

Comment: Igual a lo que dice @Gustavson en Colombia diríamos "!cuántos recuerdos!" y casi con seguridad una segunda persona añadiría "¡que tiempos aquellos!"

Comment: Acá también se se usa mucho el **¡Qué tiempos aquellos!**

Answer (score 1):

Además de las frases mencionadas en los comentarios, me parece adecuada la frase

> *recordar es vivir*

Al menos para el contexto que planteas, aunque en los ejemplos toca ajustar la interpretación en español, por ej.

> Vaya canción... de veras que recordar es vivir
>
> hace rato que no me decían así... de veras que recordar es vivir